# Perl - partial pattern matching in a sequence of letters

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, partial

I am trying to find a pattern using perl. But I am only interested with the beginning and the end of the pattern. To be more specific I have a sequence of letters and I would like to see if the following pattern exists. There are 23 characters. And I'm only interested in the beginning and the end of the sequence.

For example I would like to extract anything that starts with ab and ends with zt. There is always
So it can be

```
abaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazt
```

So that it detects this match 
but not

```
abaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazz
```

So far I tried

```
if ($line =~ /ab[*]zt/) {
    print "found pattern ";
}
```

thanks

Comment: Yes, that code should work. What is your question?

Comment: @TLP thanks. i found the mistake i was doing and updated the question.

Comment: When having problems using Perl regular expressions, it might be useful to read the Perl regex tutorial (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and reference (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). The Perl documentation is really very good. Why not give it a go?

Comment: Thanks @DaveCross .I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is a quantifier and meta character. Inside a character class bracket `[ .. ]` it just means a literal asterisk. You are probably thinking of `.*` which is a wildcard followed by the quantifier.

Matching entire string, e.g. `"abaazt"`.

```
/^ab.*zt$/
```

Note the anchors `^` and `$`, and the wildcard character `.` followed by the zero or more `*` quantifier.

Match substrings inside another string, e.g. `"a b abaazt c d"`

```
/\bab\S*zt\b/
```

Using word boundary `\b` to denote beginning and end instead of anchors. You can also be more specific:

```
/(?<!\S)ab\S*zt(?!\S)/
```

Using a double negation to assert that no non-whitespace characters follow or precede the target text.

It is also possible to use the `substr` function

```
if (substr($string, 0, 2) eq "ab" and substr($string, -2) eq "zt")
```

You mention that the string is 23 characters, and if that is a fixed length, you can get even more specific, for example

```
/^ab.{19}zt$/
```

Which matches exactly 19 wildcards. The syntax for the `{}` quantifier is `{min, max}`, and any value left blank means infinite, i.e. `{1,}` is the same as `+` and `{0,}` is the same as `*`, meaning one/zero or more matches (respectively).

Comment: I could not manage to get this work. I did the very long way and used /aa[A-Z][A-Z]...[A-Z]zt/ . This one is working. I would also like to know/print the sequence it matches. is it possible?

Comment: @user1007742: 1) Why are you using that way? 2) `[A-Z]` is for uppercase character.

Comment: I meant [a-z]. I know this is not the best way. To be more precise, i have a very long sequence of letters and I would like to capture all matches and print them all.

Comment: @user Define "this"? `[a-z]{19}` should work fine, unless your string is something else than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Just a `*` by itself wont match anything (except a literal `*`), if you want to match *anything* you need to use `.*`.

```
if ($line =~ /^ab.*zt$/) {
    print "found pattern ";
}
```

If you really want to *capture* the match, wrap the whole pattern in a capture group:

```
if (my ($string) = $line =~ /^(ab.*zt)$/) {
    print "found pattern $string";
}
```

Comment: I would like to capture the match. But this did not seem to work.it does not output anything. To be more precise, i have a very long sequence of letters and I would like to capture all matches and print them all.